# Possible to Recess Over the Range Microwave Into Wall

Tags: framing, microwave-oven

I bought a low profile over the range microwave that is 30" wide and 18" inch deep. My cut out area is 30" wide and 14" deep. My wall has brick veneer over drywall. Is it possible to cut out the veneer and drywall and attached the wall mounting plate directly to the raw studs, to save an inch or so? Alternatively, is it even possible to reframe the stud area someway to push the microwave even farther back (with the goal of making the face flush with the cabinetry)?

Comment: Microwaves tend to need some space to dissipate their own heat. Check the instructions what space it needs.

Comment: Good idea to check for any pipes/conduit  inside the wall where you plan on doing this.

Comment: I don’t think you will get an inch, most sheetrock is 1/2” and the brick paneling is usually only 1/4” possibly slightly thicker. If the Sheetrock is thicker my guess would be that it is a fire wall and then it cannot be removed. With the studs normally 16 on center possibly 24” the only way to get several inches would be to frame in a window type opening but we don’t have enough info to really suggest this option (interior or exterior wall?).

Comment: Range hood microwaves typically extend 2-3 inches beyond the cabinets. Why is it important that yours doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

If you pay attention to @ratchetfreak's comment about leaving enough space, and are willing to go to the bother/mess, you can frame up a hole in the same manner as a window opening.